# Is it possible to allow access to Webcam in the browser all the time?

Tags: javascript, html, camera

I am building a Time clock application for my employer to use with his employees.  One of the requirements is to have it take a photo from a webcam every time a user clocks in and out of the system.

Thankfully this is possible using HTML5 and JavaScript and no longer requires Flash or Silverlight.

The problem however, is in this image below....

[image]

Since this application will be used on 1 PC and accessed by a large number of users everyday, this is a real problem for my application.

I hope there is a way to permanently authorize permission to use the camera for certain pages maybe or another alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If your app is running from SSL (https://), this permission will be
>   persistent. That is, users won't have to grant/deny access every time.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/#toc-security

Note, this only applies in Chrome. Each browser may implement the security prompts differently.